# changing the layout properties on configuration change causes the view to be distorted

Tags: android, orientation, distortion

this is my xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/videoactivity"
    >

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/videoContainer"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="4"
                        android:background="#ffffff"
                      >

               <com.schoolinsites.MediaPlayer.VideoView
                                android:id="@+id/videoView" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_gravity="center">
                 </com.schoolinsites.MediaPlayer.VideoView>
                  <ProgressBar
                       android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_gravity="center"
                       android:visibility="invisible"
                       />

                 <com.schoolinsites.viewgroup.AdvertisementsView 
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="60dp" 
                      android:layout_gravity="bottom" 
                      android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                      android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                      android:id="@+id/advertisementcontrol"
                     ></com.schoolinsites.viewgroup.AdvertisementsView>

                </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list_cardId"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/card_background" 
        android:layout_weight="2"
        /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

when i change the orientation of the screen, i am changing the layout properties by using the below code but the videoview is distorted after orientation change.

```
@Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
           if(IsFullscreen)
           {

           }

           else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 
            {
                mVideo.pause();
                mVideo.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.action_search);
                LinearLayout layout =  (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.videoactivity);
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                FrameLayout bottomFrameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.videoContainer);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1);
                lp.bottomMargin = 100;
                bottomFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
                mVideo.start();

            } 
            else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) 
            {
                mVideo.pause();
                LinearLayout layout =  (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.videoactivity);
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                FrameLayout bottomFrameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.videoContainer);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,4);
                bottomFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
                mVideo.start();
            }

        }
```

how to change the orientation without distorting the videoview. can any one please help me in solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i thing's this realy if your work on 3.0+ android, in AndroidMainfest, in your activity add, `android:configChanges="screenSize"`